# How to configure DUAL-WAN on a Linux/*BSD machine?

Tags: linux, networking

I have two internet connections. The cables from the two ISP's (dhcp; 1-10/10 Mbit; 2-20/20Mbit connection) are on two interfaces: eth0 and eth1. On eth3 there is a Gbit switch and on the switch there are many clients.

How do I configure the Dual-Wan?

I mean I don't want that the clients get notice of that one of the ISP has failed, and "not serving internet"!

So if a client runs `ping 8.8.8.8` and the cable of one of the ISP is torn apart because of a [yellow monster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxlwB.jpg) :) then there would be no ping outage.

Any Linux-based OS would do (or even *BSD!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of Linux routing and networking capabilities can be found in the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control Howto](http://lartc.org/).

In particular, your specific question is addressed in [4.2 Routing for multiple uplinks/providers.](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html)